# Getting NullpointerException with autowiring in springboot (weird scenario)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, autowired

I know that this particular question has numerous answers and I am aware of the various scenarios due to which this might occur.

But I guess I am wrong, I am not aware of all the possible combinations given my situation.
Let me share the code snippets so that the code can speak for itself.

> The controller class

```
@RestController
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    ReportFactory reportFactory;

    //RequestMapping goes here!
    public ResponseEntity<Report> getReport() {

        ReportGenerator<?> reportGenerator = reportFactory.getReportGenerator("order"); //line# 43
        return getSuccessResponse(reportGenerator.getReport(companyGUID, startDate, endDate)); //geting the exception here saying reportGenerator is null!
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private <T> ResponseEntity getSuccessResponse(T response) {
        return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I am getting the `reportGenerator` which is at line# 43 which takes me to `ReportFactory` which is as you can see should be **autowired**.

`ReportFactory.java`

```
@Component
public class ReportFactory {

    @Autowired
    Map<String, ReportGenerator> reportList;

    public ReportGenerator<?> getReportGenerator(String reportType) {

        return reportList.get(reportType.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

As you can see the class is annotated with `Component` and it has another dependancy of `reportList`, this bean comes from below class.

`ReportGeneratorConfig.java`

```
 @Configuration
    public class ReportGeneratorConfig {

        @Autowired
        BeanFactory factory;

        @Bean
        public Map<String, ReportGenerator> reportList() {

            HashMap<String, ReportGenerator> reportList = new HashMap<String, ReportGenerator>();
            reportList.put("order", factory.getBean(OrderReportGeneratorImpl.class)); 
            //OrderReportGeneratorImpl implements ReportGenerator
            return reportList; //created the bean which should be autowired wherever needed!
        }
    }
```

> When I ran the code in debug, I can see that the `config` class is infact creating the bean and autowiring the same unto `ReportFactory`.
>   However the same `ReportFactory` bean is not getting autowired to the controller class.

On top of those after all the bean initialization is done, the `reportFactory` instance has null value in it's `reportlist` instance in the `controller` when I check the debug value

**But the the `reportlist` has two completely different entries, which is never mentioned anywhere, in the `reportFactory` class.**

With these Please help me out here!

> P.S. It's a webapp and I am using springBoot.

Comment: Post your error message. Does it says ReportFactory is null or list used in the ReportFactory  is null?

Comment: getting `NullPointerEXception` saying `reportGenerator` is null at line# 44. Have mentioned which is line# 43

Comment: Have you tried @Resource above Map<String, ReportGenerator>  instead of autowired

Comment: @Resource is something we use in unit testing, right ?

Comment: First check if the report factory that you see being created in the config class is in fact the one autowired to your controller, maybe there is some issue here (some clash in bean names, or libs version, i've seen crazy stuff going on i such cases), also I would try with different names on the beans (maybe those are some hidden forbidden names or something?)

Comment: @bibliophilsagar `@Resource` is same as `@Autowired`  difference is the execution paths taken to find out the required bean to inject. @Resource will narrow down the search first by name then by type and finally by Qualifiers. In your case (am guessing) the bean(OrderReportGeneratorImpl) you are adding is not ready while adding to a list. So if you change it to `@Resource(name="reportList")` it will work.

Comment: for `reportList`, Spring will autowire all the instances implementing `ReportGenerator` in your map, with the bean name as key. Your bean method which returns a map is not used.

Comment: You need to consider what dependency will be injected first if it is high precedence. so my advice is use @Order

Comment: @grape_mao that's exactly what is happening! Please help on the prevention as well.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who might visit this later on.

As suggested by mallikarjun, The following change helped me.

`ReportFactory.java`

```
@Component
public class ReportFactory {

    @Resource // It was autowired here
    Map<String, ReportGenerator> reportList;

    public ReportGenerator<?> getReportGenerator(String reportType) {

        return reportList.get(reportType.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```